# Filter one data frame by numbers from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
ID Customer Productnumber
1  1         123456
2  2         4565841
3  1         4651231
4  2         123456
5  3         456454
```

and the second one:

```
ID Productnumber Info
1  123456        A
2  4565841       B
3  4651231       B
```

Now I want to join both data frames but keep only the lines that are contained in data frame B.

I have tried it with diffrent dplyr solutions but I can't find the right way.

So the output should looks like this:

```
ID Customer Productnumber  Info
1  1         123456        A 
2  2         4565841       B 
3  1         4651231       B
```

Comment: `merge(B, A, all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: or `merge(df1, df2)`

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much. Can anyone else explain to me why I get a different number of lines with merge(B, A, all.x = TRUE) and inner_join(A, B) ? Basically, functions are the same, aren't they?